# Why am I getting `Account already registered` when trying to `/register` on a server?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

If I try to play on a server, I always have trouble. I've found out that you have to type in `/register <password>`, but it says "account already registered."

I tried the same for login, but it says incorrect password I'm quite confused. I also tried to do it with an actual password instead of the word "password", but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

When you register and it says that the account is registered, that means a player name is registered to that password. So only the player with the name can use that password to `/login`.

What you can do, is to just find another password that is not registered to anyone else and then just `/login` with that password.